# Configure hostapd to accept password multiple WPA2 PSKs

Tags: wifi, hostapd

Is it possible to configure hostapd to have a list of more than one valid passphrase that a supplicant can use to authenticate ?  Solutions I've seen so far involve setting up a RADIUS server, but I'm curious of there is a simpler solution.

I'm investigating a setting up an access point that periodically changes the passphrases from a randomly generated string.  I'd like hostapd to accept the last *n* passphrases generated in FIFO order.  The user will always use the latest passphrase, and will be guaranteed that passphrase will be valid for as long as it exists in the FIFO.

Thanks,

Comment: did you use any major search engine to find a solution to your question? which sources did you find on that topic? and what happened/did not happen when you followed the recommendations made by those sources?

Comment: The only solutions I could find involved setting up a RADIUS server as mentioned above, such as FreeRADIUS and a user database.  My question was if there was a simpler way to accomplish this with hostapd alone.